# Object spread doesn't work with generics in TypeScript? Why not?

Tags: typescript, generics

try this simple example out on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)

```
//
// EXAMPLE ONE -- GENERIC DOESN'T WORK
//

interface Car {
    fuel: number
}

function handleCar<GenericCar extends Car = Car>(car: GenericCar) {
    return {...car} // ERROR
}

//
// EXAMPLE TWO -- WORKS FINE WITHOUT GENERIC
//

interface Car2 {
    fuel: number
}

function handleCar2(car: Car2) {
    return {...car}
}
```

i find that in example one, the `{...car}` gives the following typescript error: `error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.`

what gives? in the meantime, i am using `{...<any>car}`

Comment: Relevant issue: [Microsoft/TypeScript#10727](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727)

Comment: Solved with TypeScript 3.2 :) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/11/29/announcing-typescript-3-2/#object-spread-on-generic-types